# Delegate is not being set from viewDidLoad?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, swift3

This app uses cocoa storyboard.

```
class WindowController: NSWindowController, ControllerDelegate {

@IBOutlet var progressIndicator: NSProgressIndicator!
override func windowDidLoad() {
    super.windowDidLoad()
    if let window = window, let screen = NSScreen.main() {
        let myVc = window.contentViewController as! MainViewController
        myVc.delegate = self
    }
}
// These methods are not being called 
func runProgress() {
    print("runProgress") // not being called
    progressIndicator.isHidden = false
    progressIndicator.isIndeterminate = true
    progressIndicator.usesThreadedAnimation = true
    progressIndicator.startAnimation(nil)
}
func stopProgress() {
    progressIndicator.stopAnimation(nil)
    progressIndicator.isHidden = true
}
}
```

**protocol ControllerDelegate**

```
protocol ControllerDelegate: class {
func runProgress()
func stopProgress()
}
```

**MainViewController**

```
class MainViewController: NSViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: NSCollectionView!
var images = [Image]()
weak var delegate:ControllerDelegate?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
```

**No effect of setting the delegate here**

```
    delegate?.runProgress() // No effect on setting the delegate here
    fetchDatafrom(url: URL(string:editorApi)!) {
        self.pxImages = $0!
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
        self.delegate?.stopProgress() // this works correctly
    }

} }
```

**If I put delegate in `viewWillLayout()`, than it is called**

```
 override func viewWillLayout() {
    delegate?.runProgress()
}
```

Comment: delegate?.runProgress() so delegate is nil at this point? and you are sure that breakpoint is stepping here: myVc.delegate = self

Comment: @Lu_  yes, breakpoint do stop there.

Comment: and delegate is nil in viewdidload when you run: delegate?.runProgress()  and breakpoint is first in prepareforsegue then in viewdidload?

Comment: @Lu_ po delegate?.runProgress() return nil.

Comment: and rest of my questions? :) //po delegate no delegate?.runProgress() please

Comment: @Lu_ it is nil too. Why this works when called from `viewWillLayout()`

Comment: you missed my last question :)  breakpoint is first in prepareforsegue then in viewdidload?

Comment: Try remove the "weak" from this line 'weak var delegate:ControllerDelegate?' and see if it works (Should not use strong delegates in production code though but it can be good for debugging)

Comment: I am having the same issue while initiating the view from storyboard.
Did you manage to understand what's the trouble with viewDidLoad ?